# Admob in Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, admob, galaxy-tab

I'm have an app with admob banner in it, it works fine in Android SDk emulator, but when i test it in my Galaxy tab, the admob banner doesn't come up...
but it does show in emulator..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figured it out yet, but i've come upon the same problem (we are talking the old 7 inch Tab here of course); I noticed that `AdSize.BANNER` works, `AdSize.IAB_BANNER` doesn't show in portrait, only in landscape; when I manually set the width of the Ad to 600 (which is the actual width), it still doesn't show.

Therefore looked at the docs and guide, and according to the [guide](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html):

> The SDK will request whatever size the requesting AdView was
>   instantiated with. If there isn't enough space on the device's screen
>   to display the ad, nothing will be shown.

So why doesn't the `AdSize.IAB_BANNER` work while its 468 wide according to the documentation? It is because AdMob applies density calculations on top, and since the Tab is [high density](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing), banner size gets multiplied by 1.5 such that the actual size is 702, which exceeds 600 and thus nothing will get shown.

You can manually set a width of 400, then it will fill the Ad with what size it can fit, being a banner of size `Adsize.BANNER`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download Samsung Galaxy Tab SDK and ran the project with that emulator?. In any ways, i think your problem is related to different screen resolutions. Try to run your Android emulator in a wider screen and you will be able to reproduce the problem on your development environment too.

Otherwise, please add some code to your question.

Ger

Comment: i think mate you didn't get me, it works fine with emulator, all kinds of emulators, but when i connect my hard Samsung Galaxy Tab with usb, and test my app on it the admob banner doesn't come on...

Comment: Could be a silly question, but... is your Galaxy connected to the internet?. Can you surf the web for example?. Otherwise, please provide some code.

Comment: yeah , it's connected to internet,

Comment: Also, does that happen only with your Galaxy Tab?. Did you have other devices where you can test that?

Comment: i check it on other devices and it worked fine... i don't know why but it doesn't work on galaxy tab,

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer here. can you please post your code snippet.

I guess you are using test device as emulator. If so please add test device with a proper device id.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");                      // Test Android Device
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the height of the admob banner...

For Android Tablet, the size of the Admob is 90dp for height

On my app, if I change the height of admob, then it's ok on Tablet.